# C++ bash pipe memory

Tags: c++, input, pipe

I'm using what I heard is "bash pipe command" to run multiple input files through multiple modification programs. Example command:

```
cat input1.cpp input2.cpp input3.cpp | ./calc | ./rmv_comments | ./calc
```

With this command I first run 3 different files through a program that calculate characters combined in the files, 230 + 450 + 100 = 780 for example. Once that is done, comments from all input files are removed. After all comments are removed I need to run the calculation program again to get the amount of reduction in characters.

My problem is that once I run the `rmv_comments` program between the calculations I no longer know how many characters I had originally. How or where can I store the amount of character originally? Also, how can I cout or printf the amount of reduction without messing with the output that is redirected as an input to rmv_comments?

**calc.cpp**:

```
int main()
{
    char c;
    int count;

    while(cin.get(c))
    {
        count++;

        cout << c;
    }

    // How do I store "OLDCOUNT" when this program (calc.cpp) run the first time?
    int reduction = (1 - count/OLDCOUNT) * 100;

    // How can I printf or cout the result ONLY to command line
    // NOT to output (input of rmv_comments)
    printf("Reduction: %d", reduction);

    return 0;
}
```

**rmv_comments.cpp**:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line))
    {
        char c;
        string tmp;
        for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++)
        {
            if(line[i] == '/' && line[i+1] == '/')
                break;

            tmp += line[i];
        }
        cout << tmp << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like `tee` might be what you're looking for

Comment: Not sure u really want to realize, piping commands in the bash is simple connecting their stdin and stdout. You could create something like a special format your calc understand (and your remove program generates). Its not a c++ question/problem at all.

Comment: If you want to count all the characters in your input files without the comments than look for a piece of software that offers that functionality - or write it by yourself....

Comment: You can print character counts to `stderr`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a file to store the value?

If the doesn't exist, then you know it's a first run, you do your calculations and create the file and store whatever data you need to store.

If the file exist, it's the second run, and you load the data from the file and then remove the file.